# Specify test account details for Robo test in Firebase Test Lab

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-test-lab, google-cloud-test-lab

I am trying to run a Robo test in Firebase Test Lab. I want to specify a login username for the app. The app is built using React Native. Below is the login screen for the app

[image: App login screen]

The app is built using react-native. I found the resource name for the `User Name` text input field using Layout Inspector in Android Studio. Below is a screen of the Layout Inspector for the above screen.

[image: Layout Inspector Screenshot]

The `mID` for the text input field is specified as `id/0xF`. I specified this as the username resource in the test account details and specified a valid value in the value field as shown below

[image: Test account details in Test Lab]

When I ran the test, the username was not specified and hence the test never went past this screen.

How do I specify the username in the Test Lab such that the test can go past this screen and test the actual app?

Comment: I believe resources for Robo need to be specified as the strings they are assigned when you define them in XML layouts (when writing native Android apps).  It may be the case that React naive doesn't work well with this scheme since it's not use a resource name, but rather assigning a numeric hex value.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks for the insight. Is there a way forum where I can request for adding such support for apps created using react-native within Firebase Test Lab.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that Test Lab currently can only crawl "native" user interfaces, i.e. built with the Android UI framework.

A [feature request for React](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/115948736) (and other web-based UIs) exists already, but you can definitely let the team know that you are looking for support for this.

The Test Lab team can also be contacted via the [Firebase Community](https://firebase.community/) Slack channel #test-lab.

Answer (score 0):

It takes the resourceId name without the `id/` prefix